# Go net.dial issue

Tags: go, tcp, netcat

I'm having some issues connecting to a local golang TLS server via tls.dial or net.dial. The server ist started with the address localhost:10001 and I am able to connect to it with netcat (simply netcat localhost 10001 ) but trying it with golangs's dial method doesn't work (connection refused). What could be the reason for this? One important thing to point out is that I'm testing it on a Debian VM where I deinstalled the network manager so I could configure the network interfaces myself (static ip). My guess is that net.dial has some issues finding the right interface but what does netcat do that golang's methods don't? I tried all different kinds of addresses on both sides (server on localhost, ::1, 127.0.0.1; client same). On my windows host system it works (so the issue is probably not with the server).
Thanks in advance.

```
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", h.IP+":"+h.Port, conf)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return empty
}

// do cleanup
defer conn.Close()

d := Craft_PKG( data )


//write package
WriteChunks( conn, d )
```

this is the client code and this

```
    ln, err := tls.Listen("tcp", "localhost:"+(*port), config)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return err
}
defer ln.Close()

for {
    conn, err := ln.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        continue
    }
    // start the handler for every incoming connection
    go h(conn)
}
```

the server code. It is all very straightforward and works with netcat and in my Host system as I mentioned.

Comment: Please post the go code you have tried here.

Comment: don't bind to `localhost`, bind to a specific IP address. If `h.IP` and the server binding address match exactly, then expand this into a [mcve].

Comment: But why does it work on all other systems? Even netcat is able to connect to the server.

Comment: What error message do you get when running your code? It works perfectly fine on my machine.

Comment: It is still not fixed and I have no idea why it is not working. It must have something to do with the fact that go has some issues with the interfaces. It turns out that I am just unable to connect to the server via net.dial if the dial is happening from the same host. If I connect to it from a different VM with different IP it works.